# WPF: TreeView in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I have a `TreeView` that I (finally) have been able to populate from a database using data binding.

There are 2 objects that live in the tree:

- FavoriteFolder — an object that can have children: either folders or reports.
- FavoriteReport — an object that cannot have any children: when a user clicks on this item it will run a report.

Currently I have a Model-View type setup (I think), and I would like to change it to MVVM so I can do things with the `TreeView`-items rather than simply display them.

I have looked at many examples, but I am still new to MVVM and WPF in general, so any guidance for my particular example would be much appreciated

My two classes that exist in the `TreeView` are:

Folder items:

```
public class FavoriteFolder
{
    private string _connectionString = new ServerInfo().ConnectionString;
    private string _folderID;
    private string _parentID;
    private string _folderTitle;

    private ObservableCollection<FavoriteFolder> _folders;
    private ObservableCollection<FavoriteReport> _reports;
    private ObservableCollection<object> _children;

    public FavoriteFolder()
    {

    }

    public ObservableCollection<object> Children
    {
        get 
        {
            _getChildren();
            return _children; 
        }
    }

    public string FolderID
    {
        get { return _folderID; }
        set { _folderID = value; }
    }

    public string ParentID
    {
        get { return _parentID; }
        set { _parentID = value; }
    }

    public string FolderTitle
    {
        get { return _folderTitle; }
        set { _folderTitle = value; }
    }

    private void _getChildren()
    {
        _folders = new ObservableCollection<FavoriteFolder>();
        _reports = new ObservableCollection<FavoriteReport>();

        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            cnn.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_report_folders where fdr_parent_id =" + _folderID;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                FavoriteFolder folder = new FavoriteFolder();

                folder.FolderID = reader["fdr_folder_id"].ToString();
                folder.FolderTitle = reader["fdr_folder_name"].ToString();
                folder.ParentID = reader["fdr_parent_id"].ToString();

                _folders.Add(folder);
            }

            reader.Close();

            sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_reports where rpt_folder_id =" + _folderID;
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                FavoriteReport report = new FavoriteReport();

                report.ReportID = reader["rpt_report_id"].ToString();
                report.ReportTitle = reader["rpt_report_name"].ToString();
                report.ParentID = reader["rpt_folder_id"].ToString();

                _reports.Add(report);
            }
        }

        //add the children to the collection
        foreach (var folder in this._folders)
            _children.Add(folder);

        foreach (var report in this._reports)
            _children.Add(report);
    }
}
```

Report Items:

```
public class FavoriteReport
{
    private string _reportID;
    private string _parentID;
    private string _reportTitle;

    public FavoriteReport()
    {

    }

    public string ReportID
    {
        get { return _reportID; }
        set { _reportID = value; }
    }

    public string ParentID
    {
        get { return _parentID; }
        set { _parentID = value; }
    }

    public string ReportTitle
    {
        get { return _reportTitle; }
        set { _reportTitle = value; }
    }
}
```

And the MainWindow.xaml.cs -

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ObservableCollection<object> items = new ObservableCollection<object>();

        FavoriteFolder fdr = new FavoriteFolder();

        fdr.FolderID = "0";

        items = fdr.Children;

        this.DataContext = items;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm no expert in design either, but wouldn't it make a lot of sense for your data access logic to be separated from your model?

Comment: I agree, do you think creating a seperate class that interfaced with the database that had methods for returning child elements or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first recommendation would be to drop in an MVVM toolkit, as it's easier than having to do everything yourself (e.g. implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface). I use [MVVM Light by Laurent Bungion](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).

On the assumption that you're using MVVM Light (you can extrapolate from this if you're using another toolkit)...

So, to convert this to MVVM you need to do a few things.

1. Create defined `Models`. I generally use POCO's, simply defining the properties of a model. This means abstracting out your data access layer (more below).
2. Create your `ViewModel`. This is where you'd have your properties that you're binding to in your veiw. Your `ObservableCollections` would sit here. Initializing an instance of the classes you created would go here.  Calls to your DAL layer would go here. (instead of in the constructor of your view, for example).

   Add this `ViewModel` to your `ViewModelLocator` (I use the `mvvmlocatorproperty` code snippet provided in MVVM Light).

   Bind your `View` to the `ViewModel` using the `Locator`. In your `UserControl`, you'd put something like this in the declaration:

   ```
   DataContext="{Binding YourViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
   ```
3. I would follow Brennan Vincent's advice. I generally create a service interface (note: not a class, but an interface) that defines the methods my DAL (data access layer) will have. I do this to allow for Blendability, aka design time data. If you're not familiar with interfaces, perhaps simply a DAL class is a good way to start. Then I use dependency injection (DI) to inject an instance of my DAL Service. DI is pretty simple - in the `ViewModelLocator` you need to new up (instantiate) your DAL service class & pass it through your `vm = New ViewModel(MyDALService dalService)` call. You also then, obviously, need to accept a `MyDALService` reference in your `ViewModel` constructor. Here's an example of my `EquipmentViewModel` constructor on a project I've worked on:

   ```
   public EquipmentViewModel(Services.IEquipmentService equipmentService)
   {
       EquipmentService = equipmentService;
       LoadData();
   }
   ```

This `ViewModel` accepts a parameter of the `IEquipmentService` type (which is my interface). In the `LoadData` method, I call the `EquipmentService.GetEquipment()` method of my DAL that hits my database layer.

Any questions let me know. MVVM can be a pain, but I'm very happy I stuck with it.
Good luck. :)

Comment: One thing I don't get about MVVM; the model.  So let's say I have a model with a collection of `Foo`.  Now I want to bind the collection to my UI control, so what, I have to create another collection in my ViewModel and keep that in sync with the model's collection?  Hopefully I am missing something, because that just seems ridiculous to me.

Comment: Why would you have a model with just a collection of `Foo` ? Create a model called `Foo` (aka a single instance of Foo, not a collection) and in your view model, new up a collection of your `Foo` class there.

Comment: Obviously that was an example... Ok, I have a model with an id, a collection of Foo, and a name which is a string.  Does that help?  Your example is semantically different than the one I asked about anyway.  Can you not imagine a model with a collection type in it?  It applies to any type really.  I don't see the purpose of having a model and then a ViewModel which essentially mimics all of those properties and provides PropertyChanged notifications for the view. Like I said, I must be missing something, because that would just be... dumb.

Comment: Sure.. i have models with collections inside of them. I implement IEditableObject to handle change tracking on my models. Say I have a collection of `Foo`s inside my `Bar` model. I create a collection of `Bar`s in my VM (e.g. ObservableCollection<`Bar`> Bars). If I have a grid that I want to bind to my `Foo`s, I simply have to bind it to Bars.Foo. I don't create a new collection of Foo's in my view model. That would be ridiculous and dumb.

Comment: Yes, yes it would be =).  So in this case you simply expose the model object(s) and bind to it, so they will need to raise property changed notifications instead of the VM itself.  I suppose I just don't see the need for a model at all.  I could have all of that data in my VM and bind the UI to it, and the VM would be responsible for the logic as well.  I don't see what separating the model from the VM gets you.

Comment: Yes, I implement INPC in my ViewModelBase (actually MVVM Light does, thanks Laurent!) and wrote a little code snippet (modifying propfull) to RaisePropertyChanged. MVVM Light provides a snippet to do this using magic strings, but i'm not a fan. The reason for a model is to abstract out your objects. I use my 'WorkOrder' object in at least 10 VM's in my current app.

Comment: Oh, and yes, my models also raise property changed. Not a huge fan of that, true.

Comment: Scott, thanks for your detailed explanation - I have a lot to research to do! I had watched the MIX 10 & 11 videos of Laurent on MVVM, which did help me grasp the concept of MVVM better. I will get some time to work with MVVM light a bit later today.

Answer (score 2):

Josh Smith gave the definitive description of how to use [MVVM to simplify the TreeView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx) There's not much more I can add to it.

Comment: I have read that article (several times), but as I am still learning some aspects did not make sense for me... According to his solution I would need to create some type of treeviewitem view model that my folder & report view model classes would derive from? Also, I don't quite undserstand what the "DummyChild" in the TreeViewItemViewModel class Josh used was for

Comment: The dummychild was for lazy loading. The children of a treeviewitem is only loaded on demand in that scenario. Bea Stollnitz (nee Costa) discusses data virtualization on her blog.